# Why does French have so many vowels?

Tags: histoire, phonétique, voyelles

I am interested in historical phonetic development process which resulted in French having so many vowels in comparison to other Romance languages, and even more than Latin, which I believe had only 6 vowels not counting long-short differences.

All Romance languages descend from Latin, right? And yet Spanish, Italian have only a few vowels, while French has many more. Why the difference? Was French influenced by different languages than the others? Was there a difference in the time period where French phonology developed? Different response to Latin long and short vowels?

Comment: This question requires at least a full article or chapter in order to be treated seriously;  the following for instance provides the basis of the historical developments (chronology): "https://www.cairn.info/introduction-a-la-phonetique-historique-du-francai--9782801104286-page-45.htm?contenu=resume
".

Comment: I added a summary translation to the earlier French-only duplicate.